# Several monitors fullscreen application in QT 4.8

Tags: c++, qt4

I use QT4.8 to create an application and I have two monitors with identical screen resolutions connected to the PC. How is it possible to make the application main window to be fullscreen on both monitors?

Comment: fullscreen = both monitors show the exact same content? How about screen mirroring done by your OS?

Comment: No, I don't need to show the same content on every display. I need my app to be stretched across two monitors.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code help you in some way:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDesktopWidget> //INCLUDE THIS TO GET DESKTOP INFO

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
int x=0; //OUR X START POSITION
int y=0; //OUR Y START POSITION
QDesktopWidget *desktop = new QDesktopWidget();//OUR DESKTOP INSTANCE
/*HERE IM TAKING IN COUNT THAT WE HAVE SAME RESOLUTION ON ALL MONITOR,
SO NOW WE CAN GET WIDTH BY KNOWING THE QUANTITY OF MONITOR AND
MULTIPLYING MY THE FIRST MONITOR WIDTH*/
int width = desktop->screenCount()*desktop->screenGeometry(0).width();
int height = desktop->screenGeometry(0).height();//JUST GETTING MY FIRST   
//MONITOR HEIGHT WHICH IS THE SAME IN ALL MONITORS
this->setGeometry(x,y,width,height);//NOW I SET MY FINAL GEOMETRY TO         
//MY MAINWINDOW.


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}
```

Maybe theres a faster and less code way but you can see how it works... Let me know if you need anything else.